# Upgrade Wi-Fi card in laptop

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Toshiba Satellite C55-A5387 Laptop running Win 10/64 with a Qualcom Atheros AR956x Wi-Fi card that only will run at 72.2 Mbps - My wireless network is an ac capable of 867.5 Mbps using a Netgear Nighthawk router. I would like to upgrade to a Broadcom BCM43162-ac card, or something comparable to go from a slow wireless N to a faster wireless AC card. Is this possible? I have been told to check the whitelist and I can't find any information for my computer. I may not really understand how to enter the info for the whitelist although I have tried countless times. I do have a USB Wi-Fi dongle (Netgear A6200) which gives me great speed (867.5 Mbps) on my network when my computer can find it, it is very unreliable (I have updated drivers, changed to different usb ports, deleated and reloaded the software/drivers from Netgear and nothing seems to work). So I would like to upgrade the card to solve this problem. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: If you are already reaching 72.2 Mbps your not going to get much faster with the access point you have

Comment: There is also the possibility that the firmware will refuse to boot with unknown hardware installed (not sure if Toshiba does this, but I do know that some OEM's such as Lenovo do).  Either way, you're probably going to need to open up the back of the laptop to check what type of card it is (mini PCI-E or M.2) before you can do anything further.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a bit tricky to swap out wireless adapters these days.  First of all, you need to know how to take your laptop apart, you can find that here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tFBaZKbJrw 
Then you need to understand your laptop specs and you can find that here: http://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=1200007960&osId=26 
Also - Remember that manufacturers hard code the wireless adapters to laptops and swapping the adapter will require a CMOS unlock or update.  This is not an easy task.  Your current adapter supports only 802.11b/g/n currently, so adding an 802.11a/b/g/n/ac adapter may require extra antenna leads that the laptops currently does not provide.  Anyway, I hope I haven't discouraged you.  Good luck in your endeavor.